# How to create Duplicate DataLabels in highcharts

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

So, below is my code. As per the expected output (i have attached image) in the bottom of plot bar, i want one more datalabels. also i have to show the same number in the top as well, which i have created already. now is there anyway to create one more datalabels to show in the bottom,

```
$(function () {

    //Column1 
    $('#ao-assortmentsummary-revenuepanel').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            align: "top",
            backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
            fontFamily: "Avenir LT Std Light",
            marginBottom : 30

        },
        colors: ['#5090cd', '#005baa'],
        exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButtons: {
                    enabled: false,
                    menuItems: null
                }
            },
            enabled: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false

        },
        title: {
            text: 'REVENUE',
            align: 'Top'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: null,
            align: 'right',
            x: 0,
            y: 15,
            style: {
                color: "#000",
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['HISTORY', 'PROJECTED'],
            style: {
                textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
            },
            labels: {
                align: 'center',
                reserveSpace: false,
                y: -20,
                style: {
                    color: '#000',
                    fontSize: '8pt',
                    fontWeight: 'normal',
                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                    boxShadow: "#000 0px 0px 0px",
                    textAlign: "center"
                },
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<span class="ao-label-bg ao-assortment-labelbg">' + this.value + '</span>';
                }
            },
            tickWidth: 0

        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100000,
            title: {
                text: null,
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                enabled: false

            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'

        },
        style: {
            textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    align: 'center',

                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '$' + this.y / 1000 + 'k';
                    },
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: "normal"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
                enabled: true,
                layout: 'horizontal',
                align: 'middle',
                width: 400,
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                borderWidth: 0,
                symbolHeight: "0",
                borderWidth: "0",
                useHTML: true,

                labelFormatter: function () {                   
                    return '<div class="ao-legend-wrapper">'+ series.value +  '</div>';

                }

            },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: AOAssortmentSummaryRevenuepanelData()
    });
```

my output should be like,
 [image: Expected Output]

working JSFIDDLE - https://jsfiddle.net/sarav4gs/qa9yqgqb/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the [load](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load) event and iterate on each point. In each of them, you have reference to current dataLabel, which keeps information like position. Knowing that, use the [renderer.text](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) to add new elements.

```
chart: {
      type: 'column',
      align: "top",
      backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
      fontFamily: "Avenir LT Std Light",
      marginBottom: 30,
      events:{
        load:function(){
            var chart = this,
                series = chart.series[0],
              r = chart.renderer,
              each = Highcharts.each,
              dl, bbox;

          each(series.data, function(p, i) {
              dl = p.dataLabel;
              bbox = dl.getBBox();

              r.text('$' + p.y / 1000 + 'k', dl.x + chart.plotLeft + dl.padding, chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight + bbox.height)
              .css({
                fontSize: '11px',
                color: '#000'
              })
              .add()
          });
        }
      }
    },
```

Example:

- https://jsfiddle.net/ybv3n2hz/